# Unable to delete selected rows in multiple select box in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using multiple select box and want to delete selected rows on ng-click. please help....

below is my ng-click function that is addDvc()

```
$scope.addDvc=function(sltgroup){
    angular.forEach(sltgroup,function(value,key){

       $scope.grpdvc.splice(key,1);


    });
```

**I have json object in sltgroup which is a parameter of $scope.addDvc()**

now i am trying to delete the rows with the help of key but when i am doing this so it is deleting randomly..

Comment: there is no form of `splice()` that takes only one parameter.

Comment: i know we have to pass index as well

Comment: then you should show that in the code sample, else you will likely get answers telling you how to use splice.

Comment: of course @Claies (y)